# gridview problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

i have a problem with my gridview contains a textbox to set a date.

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" CellPadding="8" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" CellSpacing="5" Height="361px" Width="748px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome Utente" 
                SortExpression="nome" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="titolo" HeaderText="Titolo Libro" 
                SortExpression="titolo" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr1" HeaderText="Data Restituzione Prevista" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Expr1" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField  
                HeaderText="Data Restituzione" SortExpression="Expr2">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expr2") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expr2") %>' 
                        AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:gridview>
```

And it is my asp.cs file:

namespace Utenti_Biblio
{
    public partial class prestiti : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        bool changed = false;

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectRow();
    }

    public void selectRow()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.Gridview1.Rows)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");
            string a = textBox.Text;
            if (a != "")
            {
                row.Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1").Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        changed = true;
    }

    // salva
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (changed)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in this.Gridview1.Rows)
            {
                TextBox textBox = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");
                string qry = "UPDATE b_prestiti SET data_restituzione ='" + textBox.Text + "' WHERE id_utente = '" + row.Cells[1].ToString() + "'";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                OleDbDataReader reader = null;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = qry;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "conferma", "alert('Data Restituzione inserita!');window.location='Default.aspx';", true);
                reader.Close();

                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

How i do to update the database when i set the date into my textbox?
The query string is not correct. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark as answer the one that works for you!

Comment: The error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: the error is in the string qry!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the ExecuteReader() use ExecuteNonQuery(), that might do the trick.

Comment: the error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: try using this instead of what you used TextBox textBox = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl(TextBox1.ClientID);   But the control TextBox1 must have a runat="server" attribute

Comment: ok but the error is in the where -> ("' WHERE id_utente = '" + row.Cells[1].ToString() + "'";)

Comment: id_utente is the first field in the row of the gridview.

Comment: then that should be ...Cells[0].Value.ToString(). C# is a 0 based index language, which means every counter starts at 0(the first column in a row has the index 0, the second has the index 1, etc.)

Comment: ok ok thanks but the problem is the row selected in the gridview..i don't know how select the row in the gridview and then get the value of cell[0] and cell[3]..

Comment: Well there should be an event on the grid that allows to declare a procedure to handle row selection. In the designer, right click on the grid and select properties, in the properties window there is an icon with a lighting bolt on it, click that and search through the events, and double click on the black box next to SelectedRowChanged i think the event is called. it should auto generate an event handler in the cs file. there use the variable "e" like: e.Cells... or something similar

Answer (score 0):

GxG is right. ExecuteReader() is use to fetch the single record(Column) while to DML(Data Manipulation Language, like INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE) we use ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: actually the reader brings all the lines a Select might return, and then you loop through the reader to get a single record, the columns are in the definition of the reader. to get a single value you may use ExecuteScalar() which brings only the returning value of a procedure, if you have an out parameter. :)

Comment: yes yes...right once again :), thanks for that i forgot that.

Comment: If you want to access the first cell in grid then you should use "0" in Cells Array like ;row.Cells[0].ToString()

Comment: that would only return a string something like "System.DataGrid.CellObject", or something similar, to access the displayed text you need to use row.Cells[0].Text, or to access the value row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()

Comment: @GxG thats common sense :), dont you think.